# JavaScript - meaning of: var self = this, textDropZone;

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

What is the meaning of the following assignment, please?

```
var self = this, textDropZone;
```

I would understand, if we assign only one value to `var self`; either `this` or `textDropZone`. However, what does it mean, if two values are assigned in the same line? Does it mean, they are added?

If you would provide me with some reference, that would help too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is creating two variables, `self = this` and `textDropZone` (which is not initialized).

To expand further, it is likely setting `self = this` because there is likely a nested scope in which they may need to access the parent scope's members.

Comment: @schmiddty: +1, Thank you for your answer. All the answers are correct, and because all of them are the same, I will select the first one and mark it as the *Acceptable Answer*. It means I am marking this one. I am assigning all the other answers +1 too.

Answer (score 3):

It's equivalent to:

```
var self = this;
var textDropZone;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare more than one variable with a `var` statement.

```
var self = this, textDropZone;
```

is the same as

```
var self = this;
var textDropZone;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's shorthand for writing:

```
var self = this;
var textDropZone;
```

You're assigning `self` to a value, and setting up a new variable (`textDropZone`) that does not have a value assigned.

Answer (score 1):

means the same thing as

```
var sel = this;
var textDropZone;
```

[Article explaining](http://benalman.com/news/2012/05/multiple-var-statements-javascript/) it and the problems of using that format.

Comment: The great Douglas Crockford enforces the more terse format, with a single `var`, with JSLint